Value based partial slicing with non-existing keys is now deprecated
When running the snippet of example code below with pandas 2.2.3, I get an error saying KeyError: 'D'
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('B', 2)],
    names=['letter', 'number']
)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]}, index=index)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
result = df.loc[idx[['A', 'D'], [1,2]], :]

Does pandas offer any alternatives for searching a multi-index with values that don't exist?
If I run the same code using pandas 1.5.3, I get the expected value:
                    value
letter    number
A         1         10
          2         20


When you run this code with pandas 1.5.3 you should in fact receive a FutureWarning:

FutureWarning: The behavior of indexing on a MultiIndex with a nested sequence of labels is deprecated and will change in a future version. series.loc[label, sequence] will raise if any members of 'sequence' or not present in the index's second level. To retain the old behavior, use series.index.isin(sequence, level=1)

(Note that it should read: "are not present".)

So, let's indeed use Index.isin to allow boolean indexing:
m = (df.index.isin(['A', 'D'], level='letter') 
     & df.index.isin([1, 2], level='number'))

out = df.loc[m, :]

Output:
               value
letter number       
A      1          10
       2          20

If you have many different conditions, you could consider creating a dictionary and use np.logical_and + reduce:
dict_isin = {
    'letter': ['A', 'D'],
    'number': [1, 2]
    }

m = np.logical_and.reduce(
    [df.index.isin(v, level=k) for k, v in dict_isin.items()]
)

out2 = df.loc[m, :]

out2.equals(out)
# True


Not sure if I follow, what's wrong with simply m = df.index.isin(['A', 'D'], level='letter') for that situation?

This indeed fixes the problem with the simplified snippet but unfortunately doesn't  apply to my larger issue which relies on the need for:
df.loc[idx[['A', 'D'], slice(None)], :] to still return an answer
More specifically if I set
number_list = None

dict_isin = {
    'letter':,letter_list
    'number': None
    }```

The above solution breaks

with python 1.5.3 I get:

                    value

letter number
A      1               10
2               20
3               30


slice(None) will just result in selecting all the values for the second level. So, just not include it. If you need to include it, e.g., with the dict, I suppose you could do: dict_isin = {'letter': ['A', 'D'], 'number': df.index.levels[1]}.

Yeah that's what I'm going to have to do. It just ends up being a messy dictionary to build would have like for the code to be more concise rather than dynamically check if the value for each key is none and not include it in said case

Perhaps there is some confusion here about what boolean indexing is. Added the link in the answer. E.g., if formerly you used df.loc[idx[slice(None), [1, 4]], :], that becomes df.loc[df.index.isin([1, 4], level='number'), :]. I.e., you don't have to "do something" with each level.

Nope no confusion, it's upstream I have to figure out if number, letter and all other possible multi-index names need to be filtered before running the is in. With the older version of Pandas less upstream work needed to be done is all, but your answer works I implemented it and got the same results with pandas 2.2.3 and 1.5.3
